# Java Converting long to bytes - which approach is more efficient

Tags: java, byte, bit-shift, endianness

I have two approaches to convert long to byte array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    data[pos + i] = (byte) (value >> (7- i - 1 << 3));
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
    data[p + i] = (byte)(newl & 0xff);
    newl >>= 8;
}
```

which of the two operations is more efficient?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Have you done profiling and seen that this is actually an issue? If not, this is a premature optimization. _If_ you know this is an issue, just try both and see which is better.

Comment: I haven't profiled and would do so, but just wanted to know in terms of # of operations performed?

Comment: By the way, the first one is incorrect. It misses an iteration, and "compensates" for it by using an incorrect shift count.

Comment: The best way to tell which is more efficient might just be to run them both a few million times, and measure how long each takes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you look at how the Java code does it.

```
public final void writeLong(long v) throws IOException {
    writeBuffer[0] = (byte)(v >>> 56);
    writeBuffer[1] = (byte)(v >>> 48);
    writeBuffer[2] = (byte)(v >>> 40);
    writeBuffer[3] = (byte)(v >>> 32);
    writeBuffer[4] = (byte)(v >>> 24);
    writeBuffer[5] = (byte)(v >>> 16);
    writeBuffer[6] = (byte)(v >>>  8);
    writeBuffer[7] = (byte)(v >>>  0);
    out.write(writeBuffer, 0, 8);
    incCount(8);
}
```

as you can see, without a loop you have less operation.

The fastest way is to not do this at all and instead using Unsafe.writeLong() as this take a long and places it directly into memory instead of breaking it into bytes.  This can be more than 10x faster.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a quite convenient solution for converting a `long` into bytes, using an instance of `ByteBuffer`:

```
    long longValue = 123858585l;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buffer.putLong(longValue);
    // without copy, accesses directly the interal array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer.array()));

    // acquire a copy of the buffer's internal byte array
    byte[] longInBytes = new byte[8];
    buffer.rewind();
    buffer.get(longInBytes);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(longInBytes));
```

However, I don't know it's performance compared to the other solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to find an alternate approach. Not supposed to use ByteBuffer to due performance concerns.

Comment: @user1071840 I see, but you will probably have to benchmark the candidates, this might be one of them. Besides, if you do benchmark them, it might be worth to check how native byte buffers perform.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer your second solution because it is clear how it works and clean that it works.
The first could easily be out by 1.  It requires quite a bit of thinking to check the bit shifts. Consider that shift and add are both single cycle ops on modern computers.

Consider you are peeling off the bytes right to left. Java traditionally uses big-endian order. You want them the other msb first.